# What are the main PII data brokers? (How do certain online companies get accurate age verification?)

Tags: privacy, data-validation, pii

A long time ago, I signed up for Apple Pay Cash. After a bit of using the service, I was asked to input my name and birthdate to continue using the service. At the time, I was underage. I input inaccurate information signifying I was 18+ to continue using the service and after a bit I was told "my age could not be verified".

My question is, how do these online services accurately confirm your age? Is it through credit reporting agencies which have functionality for identity verification? If not, what are the main data brokers for such PII?